# Using AWS Cognito can I resolve the authenticated IdentityId given a disabled unauthenticated IdentityId?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have a JavaScript web application that supports Cognito unauthenticated identities. I'm trying to figure out how to identify the linked authenticated IdentityId for a `DISABLED` unauthenticated IdentityId.

First unauthenticated users are issued an IdentityId via `AWS.config.credentials.get`. Internally `CognitoIdentityCredentials` is using [getId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getId-property) to generate a new unauthenticated IdentityId.

```
let unathenticatedIdentityId;

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = region;
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId
});
AWS.config.credentials.get(err => {
    unathenticatedIdentityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
});
```

Then our user authenticates to a Cognito User Pool via `amazon-cognito-identity-js` and the unauthenticated IdentityId changes to the authenticated IdentityId associated with their Cognito Login. The unauthenticated IdentityId is automatically marked `DISABLED` and is linked internally to the authenticated IdentityId.

```
let authenticatedIdentityId;

const { CognitoUserPool, CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
const Pool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId,
    ClientId,
});
const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
    Username,
    Password,
});
const user = new CognitoUser({
    Pool,
    Username,
});
user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
    onSuccess: (session) => {
        AWS.config.credentials.params.Logins = {
            [PoolProviderName]: session.idToken.jwtToken,
        };
        AWS.config.credentials.expired = true;

        AWS.config.credentials.refresh(err => {
            authenticatedIdentityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
        });
    },
});
```

I have the value for `unathenticatedIdentityId` and `authenticatedIdentityId` but I do not see a way in the AWS Cognito API's to resolve that the `DISABLED` `unauthenticatedIdentityId` has been linked to the `authenticatedIdentityId`. Conversely I do not see a way to identify what IdentityIds have been linked to the `authenticatedIdentityId`. The [describeIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#describeIdentity-property) API will tell me that `unauthenticatedIdentityId` is `DISABLED` and that it has no `Logins`, but it does not point to the linked `authenticatedIdentityId`.

How can I, with **only** the value of the linked/DISABLED `unauthenticatedIdentityId`, resolve the value `authenticatedIdentityId`?

Answer (score 3):

I have an app that uses AWS Cognito to obtain an identity id and then possibly authenticate it. The situation is a client uses the app first as unauthenticated (guest) and then logs in using Facebook, making him/herself as authenticated, and AWS preserves the given identity ID for the authenticated user, because he is a new user. Now, the problem comes, when you log out of the app and someone else wants to use this app as unauthenticated or even authenticated. Cognito will error out saying that the access to the identity ID is forbidden, because it has already been linked to the previous user's Facebook account.

The **Cognito mobile SDKs** have a way built in to handle this. They cache the identity id when using it, which is causing the issue you are seeing. When you log out, you'll want to clear that cache. I'm not sure which SDK you're using, but in iOS it's **AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.clear()** and **CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.clear()** in Android. Similarly, if you're using **Cognito Sync**, there's a method in that client that will wipe the cached id and sync data.

Also have a look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication/

Hope you are also following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-amazon-cognito-credentials-provider/

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but this does not answer my question. My question is about when the user already had an account but is accessing the application from an unauthenticated device. When they eventually become authenticated the assigned `IdentityId` will change and the unauthenticated `IdentityId` will be marked `DISABLED`. I'm not sure how to find out which authenticated `IdentityId` caused an unauthenticated `IdentityId` to become `DISABLED`.